# Left join not working in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I am trying to do a left join to access records between two columns from different tables but the data is not showing for one of the columns.

SQL Code:

```
SELECT [TABLE 1].[CODE 1], [TABLE 2].[CODE 2]
FROM [TABLE 2] 
LEFT JOIN [TABLE 1] 
ON [TABLE 1].[CODE 1]=[TABLE 2].[CODE 2];
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show us the data from table 1 and table 2, and your expected results.

Comment: Post updated. I added the images of table 1 and table 2

Comment: I don't see any matching values between both tables. Why are you expecting data to show for `table 1`?  What is your expected result exactly? I have a feeling that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how joins work.

Comment: I have 1.3 millions records and it's hard to search for each matching record.  I want to make sure that records in table 1 are also available in table 2

Answer (score 0):

To me this indicates that the column values are not the same, are they the same data-type?  Does one have leading zeros but the other doesn't?

The values must be a perfect match for the join to work.

Comment: I am only able to see the data for Code 2 but nothing for Code 1. Code 1 has corresponding values in Code 2.

Comment: Was Code 1 blank to begin with, did my suggestion move the problem to the other column?

Comment: There are blanks in both codes but still, there should be values

Comment: I've updated my answer, as I've realised that the join is simply failing to find matching values.

Comment: Both have leading values and have short text data type

Comment: Check for spaces, line breaks, hidden ascii characters in the data.  Copy and paste the values from each table into notepad and see if there's any difference in whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Change your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN. Do you see results? That will indicate that there are *at least some* Code 1 in Code 2.

Now change back to the LEFT JOIN and swap the tables around (i.e. "Take all records from TABLE 1 and compare with TABLE 2") and add `WHERE [TABLE 2].[CODE 2] IS NULL`. This will give you all Code 1s that do not match Code 2s. Something like this:

```
SELECT [TABLE 1].[CODE 1], [TABLE 2].[CODE 2]
FROM [TABLE 1] 
LEFT JOIN [TABLE 2] 
ON [TABLE 1].[CODE 1]=[TABLE 2].[CODE 2]
WHERE [TABLE 2].[CODE 2] IS NULL;
```

If you get no data, that means everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
Left join with sub-query may work.
**Ex:**
Here I have 2 tables. One is apps_list table, contain app info like email, application_id, application_name.
And another is daily_report, contain revenue, data and application_id. Some application has no revenue. 

**Worked:(used sub-query)**

select b.email, b.application_id, 
       d.revenue
  FROM 
  (
    select application_id, revenue
    FROM [my_db_name].[dbo].[daily_report]
    where date = '2020-11-01'
  ) as d
  right join [my_db_name].[dbo].[apps_list] b
  on b.application_id = d.application_id
  

**Not Worked: (as usual way)**

  select b.email, b.application_id, d.revenue
    FROM [my_db_name].[dbo].[apps_list] b 
    left join [my_db_name].[dbo].[daily_report] d
    on d.application_id = b.application_id
  where 
    d.date = '2020-11-01'
```